# Optimize =somproduct(---()) for combinations in excel formula

Tags: arrays, excel, formula, offset

I'm looking to combine **values** in a **lookup table** using a list of **combinations** :

```
Combinations:               Expected result:    
#1  #2  #3  #4  #5  #6      A       B
1                           =2      =6
1   2                       =2+3    =6+7
1   3   5                   …   
1   4   5   6               …   
2   1   3   5   6           =3+2+5+2+1  …
…                               

Lookup table                                
    A   B                       
1   2   6                       
2   3   7                       
3   5   5                       
4   4   8                       
5   2   20                      
6   1   12
```

What I'm doing is :

[image]

Using this formula :

```
=SOMMEPROD(--($B$13:$B$18=$C4),$C$13:$C$18)
+SOMMEPROD(--($B$13:$B$18=$D4),$C$13:$C$18)
+SOMMEPROD(--($B$13:$B$18=$E4),$C$13:$C$18)
+SOMMEPROD(--($B$13:$B$18=$F4),$C$13:$C$18)
+SOMMEPROD(--($B$13:$B$18=$G4),$C$13:$C$18)
+SOMMEPROD(--($B$13:$B$18=$B4),$C$13:$C$18)
```

I'm looking to do something with either a somproduct(offset()) or an array formula that would do it in one line.

Can post my many failed attemps but it will cloud readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What might be easiest is to add helper columns where you calculate the running sums of A and B. Then you could do a VLOOKUP to retrieve the sum of interest.

Another approach is something like:

```
=SUM(OFFSET($C$13,0,0,N,1))
```

where N is how many A items you want to sum.
Likewise

```
=SUM(OFFSET($D$13,0,0,N,1))
```

sums the first N items of B.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in I4 and drag down:

=IFERROR(INDEX($B$13:$B$18,MATCH(B4,$A$13:$A$18,0)),0)+IFERROR(INDEX($B$13:$B$18,MATCH(C4,$A$13:$A$18,0)),0)+IFERROR(INDEX($B$13:$B$18,MATCH(D4,$A$13:$A$18,0)),0)+IFERROR(INDEX($B$13:$B$18,MATCH(E4,$A$13:$A$18,0)),0)+IFERROR(INDEX($B$13:$B$18,MATCH(F4,$A$13:$A$18,0)),0)+IFERROR(INDEX($B$13:$B$18,MATCH(G4,$A$13:$A$18,0)),0)

Put this in J4 and drag down:

=IFERROR(INDEX($C$13:$C$18,MATCH(B4,$A$13:$A$18,0)),0)+IFERROR(INDEX($C$13:$C$18,MATCH(C4,$A$13:$A$18,0)),0)+IFERROR(INDEX($C$13:$C$18,MATCH(D4,$A$13:$A$18,0)),0)+IFERROR(INDEX($C$13:$C$18,MATCH(E4,$A$13:$A$18,0)),0)+IFERROR(INDEX($C$13:$C$18,MATCH(F4,$A$13:$A$18,0)),0)+IFERROR(INDEX($C$13:$C$18,MATCH(G4,$A$13:$A$18,0)),0)